# Will Moonflower and Morning Glory interbreed?

Tags: seed-saving, morning-glory

I assume Moonflower (Ipomoea alba) and morning glory (Ipomoea purpurea) must be able to interbreed/cross-pollinate since the plants are so similar... I want to grow the two plants together in my garden and save the seeds, so I'm wondering whether they will cross. Does anyone have experience with these two plants cross-pollinating?

Thanks!

Comment: Which species of morning glory? There are a lot, and they're not all in the Ipomoea genus. You mean any of them at all? I don't know the answer, but whoever does will need to know. The font's small, but this might help (I'm not exactly sure what it's saying, but it's about moonflower hybrids and morning glory): https://books.google.com/books?id=3AoiAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA18&lpg=PA18&dq=moonflower+"hybrid"+OR+"hybrids"&source=bl&ots=YTMHGdc7BI&sig=ACfU3U26XRMsZdLPLCvcitAOtJ7twhvJyg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiNlKO1uunpAhUNP30KHf9oCiIQ6AEwGXoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=moonflower%20"hybrid"%20OR%20"hybrids"&f=false

Comment: I'm not sure of the species, but after perusing Wikipedia I suspect Ipomoea purpurea is what I have and am interested in. Thank you for the article! The font is certainly small but I'm going to take a stab at reading it thoroughly. Thanks for sending it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't found records of that hybrid, just that 
crossbreeding has been done between Ipomoea nil and Ipomoea purpurea.

http://mg.biology.kyushu-u.ac.jp/Yoneda_DB/E/species/hybrids.html

Comment: Thanks! It sounds like it can be difficult to cross different species of morning glory, so maybe I'll be safe with the moonflower. Will find out by next year.

Answer (score 1):

Yes all types will crossbreed and the out come is basically a colorful moonflower with lovely markings like splatter, striping,and even color on very edges and they stay open all day!!